# Embedded Excel on webpage "this item won't load right now"

Tags: excel

I have several embedded excel sheets on two different websites egs

http://www.sportspreadsheet.com/eachwaycalc.html

http://howlongwillmyfundlast.co.uk/Calculator.html

All of them aren't loading on firefox or chrome with the message "this item won't load right now".  I re-embedded one of them to see if that was the problem and it still wouldn't load.

Is there some sort of issue?

Comment: oh and thanks for the vote down - I came to this site because it was recommended on the microsoft site - where no one has provided any info about the issue despite several people bringing it up.

Answer (score -1):

If it is from OneDrive, if you log into your account then refresh, you should be able to see the info. Worked for me, but no one else on our website could see the spreadsheets, just me, the owner.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help as the reason I use the onedrive embedded app is so that visitors to the websites can use the spreadsheets.

Comment: Funny thing is that I can see the content of the sportspreadsheet link above?

Comment: logged in to onedrive?

Comment: plenty of other people are having the same problem http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles-sdsharing/this-item-wont-load-right-now/456404f2-d1dc-4e6c-871c-f8cb61ea385a?page=2

Comment: Yeah it appears to be blocking anyone not logged into onedrive (and that isn't how it is meant to work)